# Catching errors in js promises

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to javascript and want to find out how the things here work.
I don't understand why does it output 
`testing.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Oops` instead of catching this error and handling it.
Everything works fine if I just type reject(..)
Here is the code:

```
let alex = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    return Promise.reject('Oops');
})
.then((r)=>console.log(r))
.catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: `return Promise.reject(...)` creates a new rejected promise. You do not handle the error on that promise. Returning a promise in a promise constructor does not make the constructed promise chain off of the returned one. As you point out, the correct way to do this is to use `reject("Oops")` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you should use the two arguments received in the callback (`resolve` and `reject`). As you said, it works when you use `reject('Oops')` instead of `return Promise.reject('Oops')`. It should look like this:

```
let alex = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    reject('Oops');
})
.then((r)=>console.log(r))
.catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

You can read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)